# How to apply filtering of excel workbook based on credentials?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, vba

I need to apply filtering to an excel workbook. Specifically, I need a way to automatically apply filtering to 1 column based on the login credentials of the user so that they only "see" what they need to. Ideally, this will happen when the user enters credentials to unlock the workbook or sheet. Can this be done with Javascript, VBA or a 3rd party app? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question, your choice for desktop code execution in Excel is going to be Visual Basic.  It is what macros run inside Excel.

As for can it be done?  I can tell you that there are plenty of objects in Windows to which you can attach a vb script through OLE or COM to get the current user credentials, such as WMI.

But the problem is that macros can be disabled by the user, so if this is for security reasons, you might not have the right solution given the most readily available tools - that is to say, maybe Excel isn't the place for the data but SQL Server would be a better choice.